# JFileChooser does not return control on close in Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

I'm trying to use JFileChooser to open a file. I find the file I want and click 'OK'. The dialog box goes away and the rest of the code continues to run, but the whole GUI is no longer operational. I can't even close the window, except manually through the IDE I'm programming in. However, if I click 'cancel', everything works normally. This code worked fine when I was developing in Windows 7. It does not work in Ubuntu (10.04 Lucid). My code looks thusly:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Wav Files", "wav", "WAV"));
int retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if(retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    txfFileSelect.setText(filePath); // txfFileSelect is a JTextField which is supposed to change when I click 'OK'. It doesn't.
}

else {
    txfFileSelect.setText("Test"); // this works normally
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a `jstack` (`jps` to find the pid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had left out a part of the code, so it actually looked like this:

```
if(retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
    txfFileSelect.setText(filePath);
    try {
        // Some other code where the program was actually hanging
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
else {
    txfFileSelect.setText("Test");
}
```

In case you couldn't tell by the code above, the problem had to do with the fact that the code was hanging inside a function.

Comment: No way we could have guessed this based on the original post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely on this line:

```
txfFileSelect.setText(filePath);
```

You should use a System.out.println just before the line above to inspect the filePath String.

```
System.out.println(filePath);
txfFileSelect.setText(filePath);
```

Then you should try to call your txfFileSelect.setText(...) with this String in your code without using a JFileChooser (comment it out for the time being). I'll bet you'll have the same problem.  Are you catching all exceptions?  The cause for the freeze is somewhere else in your code I'll bet.

Comment: Thanks, Hovercraft.Thanks to you, I ended up just checking the lines inside the 'if' statement, one-by-one. And that worked out nicely.